# Replace object's properties with that of another

Tags: javascript

Okay, I'm rewriting this because people kept misinterpreting it.

Given two objects `x` and `y`, I wish to replace all properties of `x` with that of `y`.

(Note that this is **not regular cloning** as that implies creating a new object (`z`). Object `x` is to be **updated, not replaced**.)

My idea is that one could do this by using two `for-in` loops (with `hasOwnProperty` checks), one for removing everything from `x` and one for copying everything from `y` to `x`, but that feels like an ugly solution somehow.

Is there some more elegant way to do this? Does JavaScript (or possibly jQuery) have some built-in function for copying the state of one object into another object that **already exists**?

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object

Comment: @Pushpesh: I'm not talking about creating a new object that is a clone, I'm talking about turning an **existing object** into a clone.

Comment: Also check out the [Prototype](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/prototype) design pattern.

Comment: You are probably looking for elegant ways to do a **mixin**, so searching for that word in conjunction with Javascript might help.

Comment: @Andy: The details about that are irrelevant to the central question. The point is that all the data in object `x` needs to be replaced with the data in object `x2`, *as opposed to* using a `.clone()` method on `x2` to create an object `x3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [jQuery.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hm, it appears to do 2/3 of what I need. (It adds and replaces but, for obvious reasons considering what its intended use is, doesn't remove.) Even then, I think I can live with manually clearing `x` before calling this. :)